# how to use xcopy to append to a file in remote machine?

Tags: windows, windows-services, psexec

I am using psexec to connect to remote windows machine and xcopy to copy few files and run the batch files present in remote machine. However the xcopy overwrites the contents of the file in the remote machine. How to use xcopy or something similar to append to files in the remote windows machine?

Or is it possible to copy a file from remote windows machine to local using xcopy or similar?

Note : the remote machine is windows and *not* running either ftp or any other service.

Thanks
Nohsib

Comment: My regrets. It would be a snap with rsync on Un*x.

Comment: True :(...but there should be some way that could accomplished in windows...some command to be called in a batch file or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Robocopy - http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

It is the Windows equivalent of Rsync.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PowerShell 2.0 remoting. Should fit most of your needs.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, i edited the question slightly...if that could help give a answer?